# SAS code in python format - examples given

Tags: python, pandas

I'm transferring a SAS script to python using the pandas library. Current the SAS code is very short a concise, however I can't find a good way of writing the python code. It a series of IF statements but is very messy in python.

SAS code:

```
DATA Table1

IF FLAG= "GO" THEN OUTCOME= 0;
IF FLAG= "STOP" THEN OUTCOME= 100;
```

I have tried both .loc and np.where and the code is very hard to follow

Example using np.where

```
Table1['OUTCOME']=np.where(Table1['FLAG']=='GO',0,Table1['OUTCOME'])
Table1['OUTCOME']=np.where(Table1['FLAG']=='Stop',100,Table1['OUTCOME'])
```

is there a way I can write IF statement in a way which is like SAS in python?

Comment: you mind sharing a sample dataframe with the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SAS`, you can use the column names as if you are referencing the variables, but in Python, you need to access the column values manually using the dataframe.

You can build almost the same code as in `SAS` with the help of function:

```
def getOutcome(x):
    if x['FLAG']=='GO': return 0
    elif x['FLAG']=='STOP': return 100
    else: return x['OUTCOME']

Table1['OUTCOME'] = Table1.apply(getOutcome, axis=1)
```

The main difference is when you are doing `IF FLAG= "GO" THEN OUTCOME= 0` that's done for a single value in `SAS` at a time, where as, that's quite different the way it works in python, you have an entire series, and you can not do it the same way.

You can just write a function similar to above, that works on a single value at a time, then it becomes easy to migrate `SAS` code to Python; however, you may not have the most efficient approach while doing this type of transformation, and there might be some more efficient way of doing those things.

Comment: ?? The posted SAS datastep operates on the whole dataset.  Plus I am pretty sure Pyton also operates on one value in a aeries at a time, just like SAS.

Comment: I didn't exactly mean that. What I mean is, it treats those values individually, i.e. `IF FLAG= "GO" THEN OUTCOME= 0;` will check each values in `FLAG` if it is `GO`, it will assign `0` to `OUTCOME` for that particular row. But that's not the same case for python, if `df['FLAG']=='GO'`, will just create an entire series of truthfulness.